# Laravel Use external data in User class

Tags: laravel, model, guzzle

Is it possible to use external data in the user class?

Most of my user data comes from a external webservice, I use guzzle HTTP for it.

To show the data (for example at the profiel page) I use:

```
$user = app('App\Http\Controllers\ExactController')->SendRequest('GET','Resource', 'ID eq '.Auth::user()->employee_id);
return $user['d']['results'][0];
```

In every controller I have to do the same thing, is it possible to make a model from it or something like that?

Comment: Define a unique key and store the data into the database and create a model for it?

Comment: Well, since that method calls a controller and you're doing that through another (?) controller then you can put that method in a base controller that all other controllers inherit from

Comment: If you are using the Eloquent authentication driver, you can add this function to your `User` model.

Comment: I use the Eloquent authentication driver, do you have an example how to do this?